# expressjs - not sending the file from view config

Tags: node.js, express, pug

In my node app, I configured the views folder, later simply I am passing the html name alone. now the html file need to load from using the views config + html file right. ( am I wrong!)

But it's not working. any one give me the suggestion please?

here is my code :

```
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    jade = require('jade'),
    app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views'); // i configured the path so i am passing file name alone on get.

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.sendfile('index.html'); //it's not working
    res.sendfile('views/index.html') //it works
});

http.createServer(app).listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ');
});
```

thanks in advance

Comment: The `views` variable is just for the jade middleware, which only recognises `.jade` files, which you would render using `res.render('file');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have a misconception about what the view engine is. The view engine takes some non-HTML code, and transforms it into HTML. Here, you have it set to use [jade](http://jade-lang.com).

The view engine is only good with the [`res.render()`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.render) function. `res.sendfile()` merely sends a file from the *current* directory -- not the views directory.

Answer (score 0):

Using `express` if you want to serve some `static` HTML files. You can just put those files directly in `public` folder.

When server will get a `GET` request of `/` it will search for `/public/index.html` serve that as response. You don't have to add `router` for that `/`.

Other wise if you want to use some `template views` then you have to use some views engine.